# Best resource for cross indexing sci fi and fantasy list questions?

Tags: discussion, meta

A while ago I asked [Are there any SciFi/Fantasy novels with a Whale Civilization at the core?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/are-there-any-scifi-fantasy-novels-with-a-whale-civilization-at-the-core)  The question was closed on account of it being "not for this site as it is a list question."  I keep coming up with questions of a similar sort, e.g. "Is there a comprehensive list of science fiction containing some kind of star gate?", or "Books/stories featuring a gray goo apocalypse?" - things like that.

Other than obsessive Googling, is there any kind of cross genre resource that can be used for this kind of research/inquiry?

I realize this is also a list question -- but I am hoping it is a list question to end all list questions, so hopefully it will be allowed to live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple that I really like:

- the [theme entries](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/category/themes/theme) at the [Science Fiction Encyclopedia](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/)
- ["If you like this, then you'll like that"](http://www.magicdragon.com/UltimateSF/thisthat.html) at the [Ultimate Science Fiction Web Guide](http://www.magicdragon.com/UltimateSF/SF-Index.html).

And the specialized entries are merely parts (great parts, but just parts) of awesome resources.

P.S. One partial way around the ban on list questions is to ask for a first appearance. For example, "What is the first appearance of a whale civilization in SF?"

P.P.S. Hey moderators, I think this question fits the main site as well as [Where can I find SF reviews?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/where-can-i-find-sf-reviews/4394) If the answers fill out more, it could be a useful resource for those who ask list questions.

Answer (score 1):

In **some** instances, TVTropes is a good resource.